# Program sends data but database does not receive it

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a conundrum.

In my VB.net program, in multiple places I communicate with my SQLserver database. I use Insert, Update and Select statements. My program is made up of multiple forms and my database has 4 tables.

All but one of my subs is working, and despite using break-points and walk through's of the code I can not figure out why.

The form and database tables in question are fine with the select and Insert statements are fully functioning, however the code of the update statement is not. When I run a walk through it behaves as if it has sent the data to the database, however the database never receives it. The connection data is identical to the functioning subs, and the code is in the same format as my update code in other forms within my program. So I can't see why its not working.

Here is the code:

```
Public selectedDeviceNumber As String = ""
Public selectedDeviceRowNumber As Integer = 0

'================================
'= Set up the DATASETS!         =
'================================
Dim PCBconnectionstring As String = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Databasename;User Id=UserId;Password=password;Connect Timeout=30;User INstance=False"
Dim PCBsqlconnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(PCBconnectionstring)
Dim damyPCB As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dsmyPCB As New DataSet
Dim ALcon As New SqlConnection
Dim ALcmd As New SqlCommand
Dim PCBcmd As New SqlCommand
Dim PCBcon As New SqlConnection
 '================================
'= SAVE the data!               =
'================================
Dim test As String = Me.selectedDeviceNumber

    Private Sub SaveToDataBaseFunctionPCB()
        'update the data entered to the database
        Try
            PCBsqlconnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ITWIN10-PC\SQL2010;Initial Catalog=SLE1000;User Id=UserId;Password=password;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False"
            PCBsqlconnection.Open()
            PCBcmd.Connection = PCBsqlconnection
        PCBcmd.CommandText = "UPDATE PCBlist SET pcbSerial=@pcbSerial,pcbPart=@pcbPart,pcbVent=@pcbVent,pcbDesc=@pcbDesc," & _
            "pcbTested=@pcbTested,pcbU1=@pcbU1,pcbU5=@pcbU5,pcbU7=@pcbU7,pcbU10=@pcbU10,pcbU11=@pcbU11,pcbVersion=@pcbVersion," & _
            "pcbTestIni=@pcbTestIni,pcbApplyIni=@pcbApplyIni,pcbTestDate=@pcbTestDate,pcbApplyDate=@pcbApplyDate WHERE pcbID=@pcbID "
        PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbSerial", txtSerialPCB1.Text)
        PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbPart", cboPartPCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbVent", txtVentPCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbDesc", txtDescriptPCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbTested", chkTested1.Checked)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbU1", txtU11.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbU5", txtU51.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbU7", txtU71.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbU10", txtU101.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbU11", txtU111.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbVersion", txtVersionPCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbTestIni", txtTestPCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbApplyIni", txtApplyPCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbTestDate", txtTestDatePCB1.Text)
            PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbApplyDate", txtApplyDatePCB1.Text)
        PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbID", Me.selectedDeviceNumber)
            PCBcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            PCBcmd.Parameters.Clear()
            PCBsqlconnection.Close()
            MsgBox("Data updated")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            PCBsqlconnection.Close()
        End Try
End Sub

     `Private Sub btnAmend_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAmend.Click
    'Save the data to SQL Server
    SaveToDataBaseFunctionPCB()
    'record activity in Activity Log
    FrmSLE1000.txtActivityLogRecorder.Text = ("Data Saved")
    'Save the Activity log data to SQL Server
    SaveToDataBaseFunction1()
    'SLE1000SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(frmConnections.lblDBConnection.Text & frmConnections.lblDBConnection2.Text)
End Sub
```

If you have any ideas then please let me know. It could be that I've been looking at the code too long and its obvious, however I can't see the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: I have edited your question and removed what looked like your password from the connection string.  Please make sure you do not include any personal credentials when posting on this site.

Comment: verify the value of `Me.selectedDeviceNumber` in `PCBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcbID", Me.selectedDeviceNumber)`.

Comment: If you are using MySQL you should use the official [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html)

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012. What I dont get is i use the exact same syntax elsewhere in my code, connecting to a different table in the same database and it works fine. Plus I get no exceptions- according to the vb.net program the data is being sent to the database, It just never arrives! But the Insert and Select statements also work no problem.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive fiddling with my code I have fixed the problem. As it turns out the problem lay further back in the code. When the Select statement was called it loaded the data into a list view, which you then select a row which you want to edit. The catch ex as exception was being fired at this point, however the data was still being passed to the text boxes so that you could edit the data, so I mentally 'parked' that glitch for later. In solving that glitch the "amend" button and Update function works fine.

If you're interested the original glitch in the code was as follows

```
        Private Sub lvPCB1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvPCB1.DoubleClick
    Dim newmachine As String = FrmSLE1000.txtNo.Text
    Try
        If lvPCB1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ensure that you have selected a PCB Board. Try again.")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'Set selected units ID number in varable to allow access to all row data to populate tables
            selectedDeviceNumber = lvPCB1.SelectedItems(0).Text
            PopulateTablesFunctionPCB()
            txtSerialPCB1.Text = lvPCB1.SelectedItems(1).Text
            'record activity in Activity Log
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Problem with selection")
    End Try
End Sub
```

and the new working code is as follows

```
Private Sub lvPCB1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvPCB1.DoubleClick
    Dim newmachine As String = FrmSLE1000.txtNo.Text
    Try
        If lvPCB1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ensure that you have selected a PCB Board. Try again.")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'Set selected units ID number in varable to allow access to all row data to populate tables
            selectedDeviceNumber = lvPCB1.SelectedItems(0).Text
            PopulateTablesFunctionPCB()
            txtSerialPCB1.Text = lvPCB1.SelectedItems(0).Text
            'record activity in Activity Log
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Problem with selection")
    End Try
End Sub
```

So it all came down to having a "1" instead of a "0" in the line "txtSerialPCB1.Text = lvPCB1.SelectedItems(0).Text"

And there you have it!